# JS / Canvas - How do I update the draw() function only when key is pressed?

Tags: javascript, loops, canvas, game-loop

edit : solved it myself, pretty sure it's not the ideal way to do it ( :D ) but it works for now :P

solution :

```js
document.addEventListener('keydown', e => {
  switch (e.keyCode) {
    case 37:
      game.toggleTurn();
      gameLoop();
      break;

    case 39:
      game.toggleTurn();
      gameLoop();
      break;

    case 40:
      game.toggleTurn();
      gameLoop();
      break;

    case 38:
      game.toggleTurn();
      gameLoop();
      break;
  }
});
```

I'm trying to make a "roguelike" game for practice in canvas and I have ran into some trouble.

What I would like to do :

I would like to implement a "turn" system to my game loop, so that it only runs when the turn event happens.

Here is some code so you can see what I'm talking about:

my index.js

```js
let canvas = document.getElementById('gameScreen');
let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

const GAME_WIDTH = 1024;
const GAME_HEIGHT = 1024;

ctx.clearRect(0, 0, GAME_WIDTH, GAME_HEIGHT);

let lastTime = 0;

let game = new Game(GAME_WIDTH, GAME_HEIGHT);
game.start();

function gameLoop() {

  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, GAME_WIDTH, GAME_HEIGHT);

  game.draw(ctx);
  requestAnimationFrame(gameLoop);
}
requestAnimationFrame(gameLoop);
```

my game.js:

```js
import Player from './player.js';
import InputHandler from './input.js';
import { buildLevel, map1 } from './levels.js';

export default class Game {
  constructor(gameWidth, gameHeight) {
    this.gameWidth = gameWidth;
    this.gameHeight = gameHeight;
    this.player = new Player(this);
    this.gameObjects = [];
    this.walls = [];

    this.levels = [map1];
    this.currentLevel = 0;
    new InputHandler(this.player, this);
  }

  start() {
    this.walls = buildLevel(this, this.levels[this.currentLevel]);
    console.log('yes');
    this.gameObjects = [this.player];
  }

  update(deltaTime) {
    console.log('update');
  }

  draw(ctx) {
    console.log('draw');
    [...this.gameObjects, ...this.walls].forEach(object => object.draw(ctx));
  }
}
```

So right now, I can start the game, generate the map, I have the player and I can move him.
The thing that bugs me, is that the "draw()" function is running in a loop, all the time.

What would be the correct way to re-draw the game, or player, only when the turn event is triggered ?

Hope I didn't confuse you, thanks !

Comment: Maybe add a variable to track the state and wrap your draw in an `if`

Answer (score 0):

You could use something similar to this. You can change the state of the `isTurn` boolean in your turn event and use an `if` within the gameLoop to check its value and stop the loop.

```
var isTurn = true;

function pauseGame() {
    isTurn = !isTurn;
    if (!isTurn) gameLoop();
}

function gameLoop() {

    if (isTurn) return;
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, GAME_WIDTH, GAME_HEIGHT);

    game.draw(ctx);
    requestAnimationFrame(gameLoop);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply ! I have already tried this, the problem is once the loop is executed, it just keeps running forever.

Comment: Still the same result, console.log("draw") keeps printing in the console non-stop